# Validation with recursive XML schema not finding expected errors in nested element

Tags: xml, schema

I have created an XML schema with long recursive path:

```
Rectangle->Rectangle_t->Content_t->TopContent_t->[Rectangle or TextBlock]
```

where names ending in "_t" are types, not elements. I'm using an XML editor with validation on the fly, and it knows a `TextBlock` is allowed inside a `Rectangle`. But it doesn't complain about invalid attributes on the nested `TextBlock` (it does catch them on a sibling of the `Rectangle`). I've used multiple validators to make sure it's not just a flaw in the XML editor.

So here is the schema (apologies for its length, it's actually boiled down some):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- definition of attributes -->
  <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Height" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Width" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Top" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Left" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Text" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="Element">
    <xs:attribute ref="Name"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="Top" />
    <xs:attribute ref="Left" />
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <!-- definition of complex elements -->
  <xs:complexType name="TopContent_t">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Rectangle" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="TextBlock" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="Project">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Component" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="Image" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="Component_t">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TopContent_t">
        <xs:attribute ref="Name" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="Component" type="Component_t" />

  <xs:complexType name="Image_t">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TopContent_t">
        <xs:attribute ref="Name" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="Height" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="Width" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="Image" type="Image_t" />

  <xs:complexType name="Content_t">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TopContent_t">
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="Element" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Rectangle_t">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Content_t">
        <xs:attribute ref="Height" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute ref="Width" use="required" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="Rectangle" type="Rectangle_t" />

  <xs:element name="TextBlock">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attributeGroup ref="Element" />
      <xs:attribute ref="Text" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
    
</xs:schema>
```

Here as an XML file it considers valid, but shouldn't be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ScreenDesigner.xsd">
    <Image Name="Main Screen" Width="200" Height="250" Fill="White">
        <Rectangle Name="Box" Width="30" Height="30">
            <TextBlock foo="bar" ></TextBlock>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text="testing"></TextBlock>
        <Image Name="Not allowed" Height="0" Width="0"></Image>
    </Image>
</Project>
```

The `TexBlock` nested in the `Rectangle` has an attribute "foo" that should be flagged as error, but isn't. If I put that attribute on the outer `TextBlock`, it is flagged. Also, it's allowing an `Image` inside an `Image`, which should also be an error.

This is my first attempt to create an XML schema, and I would appreciate any help finding out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this through Saxon's schema validator, I get warnings of the form

```
Warning at xs:element on line 21 column 74 of test.xsd:
   Local element declaration matches the name of a global element, and allows any content.
  Did you mean to write ref='Rectangle' instead of name='Rectangle'? To suppress this
  warning, add type='xs:anyType'
```

These warnings are the key to your problem. When you write `<xs:element name="Rectangle">` with no `type` attribute, you're defining a local element declaration that allows any content, rather than referring to the global element declaration that restricts the content. An easy mistake to make, hence the warning.

Comment: That diagnostic does explain the problem exactly: I used "name" when I should have used "ref" in building a type. The validator you used would have really helped me out -- can you provide a link where I could get it?

Comment: You can find out more about the Saxon schema validator at http://www.saxonica.com/ It's a commercial product that needs a license.